# Joining python string from list by using .join function is not outputing wanted result

Tags: python, string, pandas

EDIT: to clarify I changed list name for this question and I don't call it "list" in my code. It's called for what it represents, but that is not important in this topic.

I have the following list:

```
[['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
 ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
 ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
 ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
 ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
 ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl']]
```

and I need to connect them as:

```
ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl
```

Tried using for loop and join function:

```
for i in list:
        connect.append(':'.join(i))
```

But this gets me to:

```
a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:k:l
```

Can anyone help me clarify what is wrong in my script?

Comment: list is an inbuilt function, you should give your variable a different name

Comment: works for me: `>>> [":".join(x) for x in l]
['ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl']
`

Comment: it works for me, too

Comment: what's your `list` look like?

Comment: @Sayse `list` is an inbuilt function not a keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, anyway here you have a comprehension achieving the same:

```
>>> l = [['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
...  ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
...  ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
...  ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
...  ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl'],
...  ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl']]
>>> [":".join(x) for x in l]
['ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl', 'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl']
```

Comment: There is no longer an issue. Thank you. I got that my solution was in fact correct, but I was passing wrong arguments which made to split string every single character. (I have 2 strings abcdefghijkl which I split to what's shown in the topic, but to join them I was using non split one). Beginners mistakes right..?